# Posts do not appear in WP Admin

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my WordPress site. I have published 8 posts and all appear on the frontend. But in WP Admin> Post, the statement shows there are 8 posts but only 3 appear. The 5 most recent posts don't appear at all.

Comment: Are the posts of regular post type?

Comment: Could be any number of things, including templates and plugins. There isn't enough detail provided in your question to give you a definitive answer. Can you share more information? Maybe a screenshot of what you're seeing, for starters?

Comment: [SOLVED] An error occurred because the theme I uploaded was incomplete. So I re-uploaded the theme and worked. Thank you for your response.